# Pairwise cosine similarity Python

Tags: python, tf-idf, cosine-similarity, pairwise, tfidfvectorizer

I have to compute pairwise cosine similarity after computing tf-idf matrix but I am getting a memory error! found similar questions but the answers didn't solve my case.

Currently my code is ,

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import *
cosine_similarity(loinc_tfidf_matrix, loinc_tfidf_matrix)
```

Promising answer I found is [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55717/efficient-numpy-cosine-distance-calculation#new-answer?newreg=5f15cfb313e843f08eab8ace243f7e61), But I am not sure of the what is vector in that code?

Comment: what are `loinc_tfidf_matrix, loinc_tfidf_matrix`? how the error can be reproduced?

Comment: sorry it is the tf-idf matrix of size (86529, 26986). Basically its one matrix